# How to disable the automatic https redirect in Wordpress/Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed a wordpress + woocommerce website. All the pages use https. How can I avoid it? I only need http.

EDIT:
In the wp_options table I set both 'home_url' and 'base_url' to start with http in phpMyAdmin. But it does NOT work. Why ?

Comment: im not sure that is a good idea. If you are going to be passing around ppl's credit cards or any personal information then I suspect you wont be able to use http.

Comment: That data will be passed on the paypal site. So now I have to disable https. how can I do it ?

Answer (score -2):

To change and redirect the https pages anyway , you need to use the following inside functions.php

```
function force_http () {

  if ( is_ssl() ) {
    wp_redirect('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
    exit();
  }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'force_http', 1 );
```